# downloading instagram public images. url broken

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

until one month ago, the following url can be used to download public images of an instagram account.

https://www.instagram.com/{user_id}/media

e.g.

https://www.instagram.com/vodaboutique/media

It seems that that url is no longer supported. what should I use to obtain an instagram user's public images?

Comment: Yes, now even from API they have removed public_content scope to rule out any possibility to fetch "unowned" media.

you can still use API for owned media using self feed. but needs token. so works only for authenticated users.
 https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_self

Comment: when did that change happen?